# Zookeeper cfg file - Why are there multiple ports?

Tags: java, hadoop, distributed, distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper

```
nano conf/zoo.cfg  

tickTime=2000  
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper  
clientPort=2181  
initLimit=5  
syncLimit=2  
server.1=10.0.0.2:2888:3888  
server.2=10.0.0.3:2888:3888  
server.3=10.0.0.4:2888:3888
```

I'm trying to understand this cfg file. `clientPort` is for incoming communication, right? But why are there two more ports like this: `server.1=10.0.0.2:2888:3888`?

Answer (score 1):

> The entries of the form server.X list the servers that make up the
>   ZooKeeper service. When the server starts up, it knows which server it
>   is by looking for the file myid in the data directory. That file has
>   the contains the server number, in ASCII.
>
> Finally, note the two port numbers after each server name: " 2888" and
>   "3888". Peers use the former port to connect to other peers. Such a
>   connection is necessary so that peers can communicate, for example, to
>   agree upon the order of updates. More specifically, a ZooKeeper server
>   uses this port to connect followers to the leader. When a new leader
>   arises, a follower opens a TCP connection to the leader using this
>   port. Because the default leader election also uses TCP, we currently
>   require another port for leader election. This is the second port in
>   the server entry.

Ref:- http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperStarted.html